# EAjaxUpload: onCancel still uploads the image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using `EAjaxUpload` for uploading images in my project but when I cancel the process, it still saves the image I was uploading.

Here's the code:

> ```
>   <div class="thumbnail">
>         <?php
>             if ($model_account->profile_picture == 0) {
>                 echo '<img id="upload-preview" src="/resources/images/image_sample.jpg" style="max-width: 500px;" class="thumbnail">';
>             } else {
>                 echo '<img id="upload-preview" src="/'.$page_data['thumb_small_url'].'" style="max-width: 500px;" class="thumbnail">';
>             }
>         ?>
>     </div>
>     ...
>     <div class="controls" style="margin:10px 0 0 140px;">
>         <script>
>             var profile_picture_source = document.getElementById('upload-preview').src; //only to get the reference of the previous profile picture to be used during onCancel
>         </script>                               
>         <?php
>             $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
>                             array(
>                                 'id'=>'uploadFile',
>                                 'config'=>array(
>                                              'action'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/school/Profile/UploadPhoto',
>                                              'allowedExtensions'=>array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
>                                              'sizeLimit'=>4*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
>                                              //'minSizeLimit'=>1*1024*1024,// minimum file size in bytes
>                                              'onSubmit'=> "js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
>                                                                                 var loading_image_url = '/resources/images/loader.gif'; //loading or progress image while uploading
>                                                                                 $('#qq-upload-preview').css('width','31px');
>                                                                                 document.getElementById('upload-preview').src = loading_image_url;
>                                                                         }",
>                                              'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
>                                                                                 var upload_image_url = '".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/' + responseJSON['folder'] +  responseJSON['filename'];
>                                                                                 document.getElementById('upload-preview').src = upload_image_url;
>                                                                                 $('.qq-upload-success').css('display','none');
>                                                                                 $('.qq-upload-fail').css('display','none');
>                                                                                 $('#hidden_image_field').attr('value',responseJSON['filename']);
>                                                                                 $('#hidden_image_folder').attr('value',responseJSON['folder']);
>                                                                                 $('#asset_id').attr('value',responseJSON['asset_id']);
>                                                                         }",
>                                              'messages'=>array(
>                                                                                  'typeError'=>"Please upload valid data.",
>                                                                                  'sizeError'=>"4MB is maximum",
>                                                                                 'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
>                                                                                 'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
>                                                                                  'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled.",
>                                                                             ),
>                                              'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){
>                                                                                         document.getElementById('upload-image-err').innerHTML = message;
>                                                                                 }",
>                                              'onCancel'=>"js:function(){
>                                                                             document.getElementById('upload-preview').src = profile_picture_source;
>                                                                         }",
>                                             )
>                             ));
>         ?>
> ```

I've placed comments on the lines that I had problems with, I still can't figure out why it accepts the image even when I cancelled. I tried placing alerts in `onCancel` and `onComplete` then I clicked `onCancel`, the two alerts displayed respectively. Does this mean that `onCancel` does not work everytime?